# How to check if is in cart page?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, redirect

I'm creating a plugin to disable `Cart` on `WooCommerce` (even I know already some plugin doing this), I already removed the button to access cart page.

But how can I check if url is `/cart`? WordPress have some function to get it?

What I need to do is like:

```
if (is_cart()) {
    redirect('home_page');
}
```

I tried to use `is_cart` function as said in [WooCommerce doc](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-is_cart.html), but seems not working for me.

Comment: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/ check this out

Comment: I tried check `is_cart()` on my theme's `functions.php`, even this way is not working for me.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure where are you hooking your function to, but you might be doing it too early.

Hook to `template_redirect`, and then redirect the user:

```
add_action('template_redirect','redirect_visitor');
function redirect_visitor(){
    if ( is_page( 'cart' ) || is_cart() ) {
        wp_safe_redirect(site_url());
        exit(); // Don't forget this one
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a sidenote, that `parse_query` also works and is earlier